# DocumentDB paging with sorting

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I was trying to retrieve some documents from the `azure DocumentDb` with ordering and paging enabled.

```
           var feedOptions = new FeedOptions
            {
                EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
                MaxItemCount = size,
                EnableScanInQuery = true
            };
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(continuationToken))
            {
                feedOptions.RequestContinuation = continuationToken;
            }

            var query = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(this.Collection.SelfLink, feedOptions)
                .Where(filterPredicate)
                //.OrderBy(sortingPredicate)
                .AsDocumentQuery();

            var result = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();

            var responseContinuationToken = result.ResponseContinuation;
            var collection = result.AsEnumerable().ToList();
            return new PageModel<T> { Collection = collection, ContinuationToken = responseContinuationToken };
```

This works fine without the ordering. But when I add the `OrderBy(sortingPredicate)` then it returns a text `"ParallelDocumentQueryExecutionContext"` in the `responseContinuationToken`.

I am wondering why does it behave like this?

**Edit:**

I have already added the

> Range type indexing

for all the properties, so that's not an issue here and it is also ordering the items as expected. But the problem I faced is with the paging. I have thousands of documents in the collection and I just want to page them with 20 entries in each set. So, when I remove the orderBy predicate, it works without ordering, it gives me 20 documents on each page. I just forward the continuation token. And this continuation token is a random string that changes every time. But when I user OrderBy the `result.ResponseContinuation` returns `"ParallelDocumentQueryExecutionContext"` instead of a random string. As a result, though it is sorted it returns the same result every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the partition key. The **partition key** was not provided, that's why it was returning the same result over and over again. After providing the right **partition key**, it was working.

Answer (score 1):

Order by is supported in the Azure documendb if we create a collection with "All Range" indexing for Order By against any/all numeric or string properties that appear within JSON documents within it. More details please refer to [document](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/documentdb/documentdb-orderby.md).

```
DocumentCollection books = new DocumentCollection();
books.Id = "books";
books.IndexingPolicy = new IndexingPolicy(new RangeIndex(DataType.String) { Precision = -1 });

await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri("dbname"), books);
```

I can't repro the issue that you mention on my side.

[image]

I assume it is caused by your oderby sortingPredicate, and we may troubleshot with following ways:

1. Try to execute the SQL query  in the Azure portal, if it failed we can get more detail info about that.

[image]

[image]

2. From the [document](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/documentdb/documentdb-orderby.md) we also know that we cannot perform the following action currently

> Order By with internal string properties like id, _rid, and _self (coming soon).
>
> Order By with properties derived from the result of an intra-document join (coming soon).
>
> Order By multiple properties (coming soon).
>
> Order By with queries on databases, collections, users, permissions or attachments (coming soon).
>
> Order By with computed properties e.g. the result of an expression or a UDF/built-in function.

Note: If it is not resolved, could please share your `OrderBy(sortingPredicate)`.

**Edit:**

I can't repro the issue that you mentioned on my side, I also can get the next page when with groupby and responseContinuation .

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited my question according to your query. Please take a look

Comment: I can't repro the issue on my side. I also can get the next page when with groupby and responseContinuation. More details please refer to the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I have figured out my problem. I have did not provide the partition key. That was the main problem. After providing the partition key it was working correctly. :)